# Javascript animate for multiple ids

Tags: javascript

I'm using this Javascript function for animate text change:

```
function changeText(id, newText) {
    item = document.getElementById(id);
    if (item === null) {
        return false
    }
    let animation = item.animate([
        // keyframes
        {transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: '1'},
        {transform: 'translateY(1px)', opacity: '0.9'},
        {transform: 'translateY(4px)', opacity: '0.7'},
        {transform: 'translateY(9px)', opacity: '0.5'},
        {transform: 'translateY(14px)', opacity: '0.3'}

    ], {
        // timing options
        duration: 500,
    });
    animation.onfinish = function () {
        item.innerText = newText;
        item.animate([
            // keyframes
            {transform: 'translateY(14px)', opacity: '0.3'},
            {transform: 'translateY(9px)', opacity: '0.5'},
            {transform: 'translateY(4px)', opacity: '0.7'},
            {transform: 'translateY(1px)', opacity: '0.9'},
            {transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: '1'}
        ], {
            // timing options
            duration: 500,
        });
    };
}
```

If i'm using the funtion for a single element, it works fine:

```
changeText('random1', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "°")
```

But if i'm using for two different element not:

```
changeText('random1', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "°")
changeText('random2', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "°")
```

It will update only one of the two element, the second one.

There is any technical reason why i can't use for different IDs? How can i solve?
Thanks

EDIT: A JFiddle for testing:
https://jsfiddle.net/5yf7gcjw/

Comment: What happens when you use it for two different elements? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: It update only once of the two, i'll add to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `item` using `let` or `const` to avoid it becoming a global variable.

```js
const item = document.getElementById(id);
```

```js
function changeText(id, newText) {
    const item = document.getElementById(id);
    if (item === null) {
        return false
    }
    let animation = item.animate([
        // keyframes
        {transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: '1'},
        {transform: 'translateY(1px)', opacity: '0.9'},
        {transform: 'translateY(4px)', opacity: '0.7'},
        {transform: 'translateY(9px)', opacity: '0.5'},
        {transform: 'translateY(14px)', opacity: '0.3'}

    ], {
        // timing options
        duration: 500,
    });
    animation.onfinish = function () {
        item.innerText = newText;
        item.animate([
            // keyframes
            {transform: 'translateY(14px)', opacity: '0.3'},
            {transform: 'translateY(9px)', opacity: '0.5'},
            {transform: 'translateY(4px)', opacity: '0.7'},
            {transform: 'translateY(1px)', opacity: '0.9'},
            {transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: '1'}
        ], {
            // timing options
            duration: 500,
        });
    };
}
changeText('random1', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "°")
changeText('random2', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "°")
```

```html
<div id="random1">
  Random1
</div>
<div id="random2">
  Random2
</div>
```

Comment: You have right, i have forget it. Thanks!